# rails, how to write a callback function after ajax request is finished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, callback

i was wondering how/where to write a callback function after an ajax request is complete?

im building a twitter app and im trying to send an email notification after a user clicks 'follow'. the following/unfollowing is done using ajax. when a user clicks follow, i have...

```
  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end
```

which in turns calls

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @user}
        format.js
    end

    UserMailer.is_now_following(@user, current_user).deliver
  end
```

however, by adding that UserMailer line, it lags my ajax a lot. where/how should i put the email request instead? i was thinking of a callback function after the ajax is finished, but im not sure where to add it or how.

sorry i still quite new to this. thanks a lot!

hmmm, i found out that maybe a good way to do this is to use jquery. i decided to give the follow button

```
<%= f.submit "Follow", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", 
        :id => "follow_button"%>
```

an id and used jquery

```
$("#follow_button").bind('ajax:success', function() {

});
```

to send the email afterwards. however, im really sure how i could pass in variables. the ultimate line i want to achieve would be

```
UserMailer.is_now_following(@user, current_user).deliver
```

current_user is a function btw which assigns/returns the current_user

how would i do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These railscasts series are pretty old, but may be helpful

http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background

http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling

http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

Resque - https://github.com/resque/resque

Sidekiq - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Delayed Job - https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job